# Passing JSON data from server to client with Flask

Tags: python, json, d3.js, flask

I'm completely new to Flask and am trying to figure out how to display networkx graph data with d3js force layouts. Here is the relevant Python code:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    """
    When you request the root path, you'll get the index.html template.

    """
    return flask.render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/thread")
def get_graph_data(thread_id: int=3532967):
    """
    returns json of a network graph for the specified thread
    :param thread_id:
    :return:
    """
    pqdict, userdict = graphs.get_post_quote_dict(thread_id)
    G = graphs.create_graph(pqdict)
    s = graphs.graph_to_node_link(G, remove_singlets=True) # returns dict
    return flask.jsonify(s)
```

And here is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index thing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="templates/graph.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
    var w = 1500,
        h = 1500,
        fill = d3.scale.category20();

    var vis = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    d3.json("/thread", function (json) {
        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .charge(-120)
            .linkDistance(30)
            .nodes(json.nodes)
            .links(json.links)
            .size([w, h])
            .start();

        var link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
            .data(json.links)
            .enter().append("svg:line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
                return Math.sqrt(d.value);
            })
            .attr("x1", function (d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
            .attr("y1", function (d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr("x2", function (d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr("y2", function (d) {
                return d.target.y;
            });

        var node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
            .data(json.nodes)
            .enter().append("svg:circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return d.y;
            })
            .attr("r", 5)
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return fill(d.group);
            })
            .call(force.drag);

        vis.style("opacity", 1e-6)
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .style("opacity", 1);

        force.on("tick", function () {
            link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            node.attr("cx", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
                .attr("cy", function (d) {
                    return d.y;
                });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So clearly the d3.json() function wants a location of a static JSON file, which in this case I'm trying to generate dynamically based on the request URL.

I've tried about a dozen approaches that I've found around here. Per the suggestion below, I tried:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    """
    When you request the root path, you'll get the index.html template.

    """
    return flask.render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/thread")
def get_graph_data():

    """
    returns json of a network graph for the specified thread
    :param thread_id:
    :return:
    """
    thread_id = request.args.get("thread_id", 3532967, type=int)
    pqdict, userdict = graphs.get_post_quote_dict(thread_id)
    G = graphs.create_graph(pqdict)
    s = graphs.graph_to_node_link(G, remove_singlets=True)
    return jsonify(s)
```

With the template index.html unchanged, and navigated to "http://localhost/thread?thread_id=12345" but this failed because it was printing the JSON for ID 12345 on the page instead of rendering the javascript.

So to sum up, my current goal is to specify a parameter in the Python method from the URL (".../showgraph?threadid=whatever..."), generate a json in the Python code, and pass it back to the html/js. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are really close!

First off, the statement: "clearly the d3.json() function wants a location of a static JSON file" is not correct.

[d3.json()](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json) is part of the `d3-request` library and, as such, is an XHR method (e.g. expects a URL, which could be a static JSON like `data.json`, but not literal JSON data).

I would adjust your Flask route to accept a `GET` parameter as the function will only accept a parameter via the URL:

```
@app.route("/thread")
def get_graph_data():
    thread_id = request.args.get("thread_id", 3532967, type=int)
    pqdict, userdict = graphs.get_post_quote_dict(thread_id)
    G = graphs.create_graph(pqdict)
    s = graphs.graph_to_node_link(G, remove_singlets=True) # returns dict
    return flask.jsonify(s)
```

*What I mean here is if you want to use the function parameter you'd need to do something like this:*

```
@app.route("/thread/<int:thread_id>")
def get_graph_data(thread_id):
    ...
```

Then, adjust your XHR call a bit to send the GET parameter:

```
var url = "/thread?thread_id=" + id.toString();
d3.json(url, function (json) {
    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-120)
        .linkDistance(30)
        .nodes(json.nodes)
        .links(json.links)
        .size([w, h])
        .start();

   // a bunch more js that i copied and pasted from a tutorial
});
```

And it should be fine.

Also, FYI, if you ever want to use Jinja2 to "read" an object into a Javascript Object you need to use 2 filters: `{{ data|tojson|safe }}`

Comment: So from what you're saying, I'm gathering that d3.json() accepts a URL (i.e. a static file or something from a REST API), but to do that I'll need to invoke a separate method somehow to actually render the template, won't I? I tried a (slightly modified--`request.args.get` instead of `requests.get`) version of your first snippet suggestion but it just prints the raw JSON on the page instead of rendering the JS. This was another issue I ran into repeatedly...

Comment: yes it's an asynchronous method so accepts any valid http URL. The requests.get was an error, good catch. Can you explain in more detail what is happening? Maybe share more code.

Comment: I pasted almost all of my code in its entirety (omitted imports and the "if __name__ == '__main__'" bit) and I think I might be doing something wrong in my approach... when I go to the url `[domain]/thread?thread_id=12345` it does all the right backend stuff, but it just literally prints { "source": 1, "target": 2 } etc on the page instead of rendering that JSON. Maybe I shouldn't be going directly to the URL?

Comment: Yes i assume you were loading an html page and then calling this route using d3.json so it would load asynchronously

Comment: I think I'm not being clear and it's confusing... if I want to use your first Python snippet, this requires that I use your last javascript snippet--otherwise "/thread" is always going to return the default path. And that requires that I pass "12345" into something so that "id.toString()" returns 12345, and thus the d3.json parameter becomes "/thread?thread_id=12345", right? I don't understand what "id.toString()" refers to or how to pass that 12345 into d3.json

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on the `.toString()`. You figured it out!

Answer (score 3):

The solution was:

Python:

```
@app.route("/thread")
def get_graph_data():

    """
    returns json of a network graph for the specified thread
    :param thread_id:
    :return:
    """
    thread_id = request.args.get("thread_id", 3532967, type=int)
    pqdict, userdict = graphs.get_post_quote_dict(thread_id)
    G = graphs.create_graph(pqdict)
    s = graphs.graph_to_node_link(G, remove_singlets=True)
    return json.dumps(s)


@app.route("/showgraph")
def showgraph():
    thread_id = request.args.get("thread_id", 3532967, type=int)
    return render_template("index.html", threadid=thread_id)
```

HTML/Jinja2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index thing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="templates/graph.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
    var w = 1500,
        h = 1500,
        fill = d3.scale.category20();

    var vis = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    d3.json("/thread?thread_id={{ threadid }}", function (json) {
        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .charge(-120)
            .linkDistance(30)
            .nodes(json.nodes)
            .links(json.links)
            .size([w, h])
            .start();

        // irrelevant stuff
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Needed separate methods to return the JSON and render the page. Still seems silly to have to parse the thread_id arg twice but whatever. Accepted PJ's answer since it was 99% of the issue!